# how to load image from server - ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

For some reason when I open the application in some emulator, the qrcode image is not displayed, but in the browser it is displayed normally.

how can i solve this problem?

I tried to use axios to solve the problem but it is also only displayed in the browser.

Is there any other way to resolve this image loading or is the code incomplete or incorrect?

[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-qrcode',
  templateUrl: './qrcode.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./qrcode.component.scss'],
})
export class QrcodeComponent implements OnInit {

  imageUrl: SafeUrl = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.loadQrCode()
  }

  loadQrCode() {
    this.http.get('ENDPOINT', {

      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
      .subscribe(response => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          const base64Image = reader.result as string;
          this.imageUrl = base64Image;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(response);
      });
  }
}
```

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title>QrCode</ion-card-title>
    <ion-card-content>
      <img [src]="imageUrl" width="200" height="200">
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url format should be

```
this.imageUrl ="data:image/png;base64,"+base64Image;
```